# Connect Mobile phone/ GSM modem to a VPS or hosting dedicated server

Tags: usb, remote-desktop, port, modem, vps

I have a Nokia E71 phone that I am using for as a GSM modem to send out SMS (text message) through the web application I wrote. Everything is working fine on my local machine and now I am looking to host this application on a VPS (part of a large application already running on VPS) and use this phone to as GSM modem.

So what I am thinking to do is to connect the phone to local machine and somehow use port redirection in Remote Desktop (RDP) to achieve this.

**is this even possible?**

**If Yes:** how do I use port redirection in RDP, as I have never use it before and I have just tried but failed  with Windows 7 Pro machine (if required I also have Win server 2008 R2 available)

**If No:** what is the best way to achieve this.

**FYI:** I am trying to avoid using an online SMS gateway because of economic reasons.

**Port:** COM 6 > Bits per second: 9600